# I need quartz scheduler to ignore misfire

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I am using quartz to schedule some jobs.
My job doesn't care about misfire. I'd like quartz not reschedule this round.
I am using simpleTrigger.

Could anyone please give me some hint?
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you want to set something like

```
MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_IGNORE_MISFIRE_POLICY
```

Read the Java-doc for more details

[MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_IGNORE_MISFIRE_POLICY](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.0.0/org/quartz/Trigger.html#MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_IGNORE_MISFIRE_POLICY)

Comment: Umesh is correct. Also, you can configure the misfire threshold in the quartz.properties to be some huge value (e.g. years) and then no triggers will ever be considered misfired.

Comment: @jhouse: If we increase misfire_threashhold to such a large value, then the trigger will execute at any available time when the system comes up after several months. Logically, there won't be such business cases wherein you want such an older job to be fired at a certain time in future.